# IllegalAccessError in a Gradle project when using any JavaFX instruction

Tags: java, gradle, javafx

Goodday, community!

Whenever I try to use a JavaFX instruction within my Gradle project, I get an IllegalAccessException. I cannot seem to be able to find the source of this, except for maybe a faulty Gradle import (it is my first time using it). I followed the instructions found here: https://github.com/openjfx/javafx-gradle-plugin. Also, for the project, I am using JDK 12.

Here you can have a glance at some JavaFX code:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;

import javafx.scene.Scene;

import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;

public class HelloWorld extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws IOException {

        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.setText("Say 'Hello World'");
        btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                System.out.println("Hello World!");
            }
        });

        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(btn);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 250));
        primaryStage.show();
    }



    public static void main(String[] args) {

        launch(args);
    }
}
```

The stack trace is (please note that line 20, that throws the error, is the initalization of a Button, the first line involving JavaFX):

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:464)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:363)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1051)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:900)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:195)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:835)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: superclass access check failed: class com.sun.javafx.scene.control.ControlHelper (in unnamed module @0x603a69d1) cannot access class com.sun.javafx.scene.layout.RegionHelper (in module javafx.graphics) because module javafx.graphics does not export com.sun.javafx.scene.layout to unnamed module @0x603a69d1
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1016)
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:151)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:802)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:700)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:623)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    at javafx.scene.control.Control.<clinit>(Control.java:86)
    at HelloWorld.start(HelloWorld.java:20)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:846)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:455)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:428)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:389)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:427)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
    ... 1 more
Exception running application HelloWorld
```

and the way I import JavaFX in Gradle is:

```
plugins {

    id "org.openjfx.javafxplugin" version "0.0.8"
    id "application"
}
javafx {
    version = '13'
    modules = [ 'javafx.controls', 'javafx.fxml' , 'javafx.graphics']
}
```

Please let me know if you know what might cause this problem.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are you running a Gradle task (like `application -> run` or `./gradlew run`) or are you running from your IDE like a Java application? It looks the latter...

Comment: Thank you, I did not know there was a difference between the 2.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java IllegalAccessError can't run Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57952124/java-illegalaccesserror-cant-run-application)

Comment: Add your JavaFX modules to your module path. Check out here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57952124/java-illegalaccesserror-cant-run-application/57964921#57964921

Comment: There is: if you use a build tool like Gradle, you want it to do the tasks you have defined. Letting the IDE do that for you (if running as Java Application) is not the same, as it doesn't apply the same configuration. Of course, this should work as well when done properly (adding `--module-path`, `--add-modules`, as explained here: https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#IDE-Intellij)